# How is Amazon EBS disk space shared across instances?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, storage, amazon-ebs, availability-zone

If a 2GB Amazon EBS volume is attached to 2 Amazon EC2 instances, is that EBS space divided per EC2 instance or is that space of 2GB is available for all of the EC2 instances?

Comment: Are you using [Amazon EBS Multi-Attach](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2020/02/ebs-multi-attach-available-provisioned-iops-ssd-volumes/)?

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about EBS Multi-Attach, then the 2gb is shared/available for all EC2 instances.